Relation does not exist when running Django Unit Tests
I am having trouble running unit tests in my django app when it is running through Jenkins.
I have a CI/CD pipeline which runs python manage.py test which is currently failing with the error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist.
Running tests locally works fine and the test database is normally created and the tests are ran normally.
I SSH-ed into the server where Jenkins is set up to try and manually run the tests but I get the same results, so I wouldnt' say it's anything Jenkins specific.
The postgres user has all privileges and CREATEDB on the database so postgres side seems to all be good.
This is the complete exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "auth_user" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 68, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 1045, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 941, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 220, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 78, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 198, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 314, in handle
    self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 480, in sync_apps
    self.stdout.write("    Running deferred SQL...")
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 164, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 199, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/agent/jenkins/workspace/INP-Backend/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist

EDIT
I don't believe this question should be flagged as a duplicate. I had a very specific problem where the migrations were not entirely ran because of a missing migrations directory / __init__.py file. This was particularly harder to debug since the tables come from a third party package that was installed.

did you try to run python manage.py migrate?

Yes, migrations are normal. Checking into the usual database, I can see all the tables, including the 'auth_user' are there. However I don't think this is relevant since django creates a new test database and automatically migrates it.

That's true. I thought it might give some clues.

As for clues, all the migration files for around ~30 apps are correctly created and migrate creates all the tables without any errors.

Do you have a single db configuration in settings, or multiple?

and do you happen to have any models without migrations, e.g. defined in your tests?

It's only a single db configuration in the settings. No models are without migrations, I manually went into my staging server, where another instance of the same application is. Pulled the latest, ran the new migrations without issues and ran the tests without issues. This all seems to be pointing to some problem with creating the test database in the jenkins environment. However, I have no idea where to even start debugging as it just looks like a normal missing migration error.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The traceback suggests Django didn't even start running the tests yet, it errored out while running the migration for the test database. Are you able to run the migrations for a fresh database or does it similarly error out?

some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56355516, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50544714, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69495933

@AbdulAzizBarkat IMHO the question should remain open, as the links provided do not answer this specific question: The current problem occurs only when running tests, and OP explicitly mentions that migrations have succeeded.

@djvg a migration will 100% fail for a fresh database in OPs case as well it only worked for them because they already had an existing database. The problem is basically the same. Duplicate closure does not mean the question is bad BTW, this can stay as a signpost for that question :) (IMO that question's answers are much more clear than the one posted here)

@djvg to clarify, the failure here is also in the migrations only. One of the steps of setting up the test database is to run the migrations on it.

I have posted an answer below as to what resolved my issue. However, I still am not quite sure why that resolved it. When Django creates a test database for unit testing, it should run automatic migrations on that database. If I was missing tables for a model that is not being used in the unit tests, why would that throw an exception?

@AbdulAzizBarkat I had run new migrations on a fresh database. To clarify, with no previous migration files and on an empty database. The migrations all succeeded. The tables from the third party app weren't created, but migrations weren't throwing an error, as well as all the other parts of the app. Everything esentially works except for that third party app, which is a development tool.

"with no previous migration files and on an empty database" is different from "no previously applied migrations". Generating new migration files (You shouldn't be doing this in production!) isn't really an effective comparision (The migrations are like a dependency tree), if you run with the same migration files (same installed apps, etc.) you'll be able to reproduce the error. Again the error doesn't really have to do with the tests, running the tests involves running the migrations against the test database which is what is erroring.

I have resolved the issue. After @djvg mentioned models without migrations, I did a deeper dive. Turns out an application wasn't being automatically migrated and had to be have manual migrations ran for it.
I still have no idea why this stopped the tests completely, since that app has no dependencies on other apps and is not being used in test cases, but migrating that app specifically resolved my problem.

Oh so the app that had your custom user model didn't have any migration directory or the directory was missing an __init__.py file?

That's correct. Actually it was a third party package that was installed that had the missing __init__.py file, so it doesn't automatically migrate it.

If it's a third party app you should avoid creating the migrations for them. If the case is that it was just missing the __init__.py file and you didn't actually generate any migrations for it that should be fine. In either case you should report this to the app maintainer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38277776
